# Disabling the title bar in landscape mode

Tags: android

Noob here, having an issue with the action bar in landscape mode (want to keep it in portrait mode).

I post a sample of my manifest xml file having tried the info in other threads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my styles.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Primary theme color of the app (sets background color of app bar) -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffcfcf</item>
    <!-- Background color of buttons in the app -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#ff8383</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

a snippet from my land\activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:style="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/love3"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

...

I have tried changing the parent in styles.xml from AppTheme to Theme.AppCompat.Light to no avail.

portrait layout xml does not have android:style="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in onCreate function below setContentView

```
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this,

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else {
  getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Would this java be used instead of the above or in addition ?

Comment: You can Add this code snippet inside your MainActivity class.